# decrypt multiple OpenPGP files in a directory

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

I have several hundred gpg encrypted files in a directory, of the format filename.xyz.gpg where "xyz" is some arbitrary extension. I need to decrypt all of the files to generate filename.xyz decrypted in such a way that I don't have to manually enter the password for each file.

I have tried the following for directory "Testing":

```
for file in 'ls Testing'; do (echo <password>|gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -d $file 
--output     $file.decrypted);
```

I just wind up with a command prompt >, and nothing happens.

What is the matter with my syntax? Is there some more efficient way to do this without a bash shell loop?

Comment: Maybe swap echo password with gpg command? Echo'ing password before command is ok?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it is said in the manual you need to add `--batch` option:

```
   --passphrase-fd n
          Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line will be read from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the passphrase will be read from
          STDIN. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied.  Note that this passphrase is only used if the option --batch has also been given.  This is
          different from gpg.

   --passphrase string
          Use string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable security on a multi-user sys‐
          tem. Don't use this option if you can avoid it.  Note that this passphrase is only used if the option --batch has also been given.  This is different from
          gpg.
```

You can have either of these two forms:

```
echo "passphrase" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch -d --output "decrypted.file" "file.gpg"
```

Or simpler:

```
gpg --passphrase "passphrase" --batch -d --output "decrypted.file" "file.gpg"
```

You can try a script like this to extract your files:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rsp "Enter passphrase: " PASSPHRASE

for FILE in *.*.gpg; do
    echo "Extracting $FILE to ${FILE%.gpg}."
    echo "$PASSPHRASE" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch -d --output "${FILE%.gpg}" "$FILE"
done
```

Comment: Not sure it's great to have the passphrase in the command line like this as then it becomes visible to all users on the system using ps and similar tools

Answer (score 28):

`gpg` can decrypt multiple files so you shouldn't need to write a loop.

Try the following. You will need to enter your password once.

```
gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt-files *.gpg
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly makes it easier. I also found some documentation suggesting the use of --multifile for situations like this, so that the passphrase has to only be entered once. Incidentally, I like your leaf beetle avatar!

Comment: thanks. It's a [dogbane leaf beetle](http://www.museum.state.il.us/muslink/prairie/htmls/popups/insects_dgbeetle.html) if you're interested!

Comment: --decrypt-files should be the same as --multifile --decrypt anyway.

Comment: With my current version of gpg I just need `gpg --decrypt-files *.gpg` \o/

Answer (score 5):

I had success with

```
gpg --decrypt-files *.gpg
```

cf. https://serverfault.com/a/388068/103585

Answer (score 0):

I had success with gpg --decrypt-files * 
but not *.gpg

Answer (score 0):

It worked with below commands for me:

For single file:
`gpg --decrypt --input C:\PGPFiles\[encryptedfilename.pgp] --passphrase [yourpassphrase]`

For multiple files:
`gpg --decrypt --input C:\PGPFiles\* --passphrase [yourpassphrase]`